# Laravel 5.6 Changing redirect with unauth with guards

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-middleware

I have an admin and the regular web guard that Laravel 5.6 comes with. As i have seen that Laravel 5.5 up has changed their Exceptions.php file located in \app\Exceptions\Exceptions.php so that the function:

```
   /**
     * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest('/login');
    }
}
```

is no longer there. And in order for the

> $this->middleware('auth:admin');

to work and redirect to the admin login and not the just "/login" i needed this method to be in this Exception file. I read on here that you could just copy this and use it as the only thing it did was override and Laravel removed it for some reason. But to the point, In order for me to make my switch statement that makes the method look like this:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);

            $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
            switch($guard) {
                case "admin":
                    $login = "admin-login";
                    break;
                default:
                    $login = "login";
                    break;
            }
        }

        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }
```

But when trying to load to see if it redirects to the admin login when going to the /admin/login, it says

> Undefined variable: login

What is the issue? I am guessing it has to do something with the $guard, but i am unsure. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, issue in above code is quite obvious.

In

```
return redirect()->guest(route($login));
```

you use `$login` variable and it might be not defined because you define it only for condition:

```
if ($request->expectsJson()) {
```

so to make it work, you should probably end if condition before like so:

```
if ($request->expectsJson()) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
}

$guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
switch($guard) {
    case "admin":
        $login = "admin-login";
        break;
    default:
        $login = "login";
        break;
}

return redirect()->guest(route($login));
```

Of course above code is in fact too long, it could be just:

```
if ($request->expectsJson()) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
}

$login = array_get($exception->guards(), 0) == 'admin' ? 'admin-login' : 'login' 

return redirect()->guest(route($login));
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the later versions of laravel (7.x), you could get a couple of errors due to a number of deprecations, such as;

1. Laravel has removed its Exceptions.php file located in `App\Exceptions\Exceptions.php`, as already stated.
2. The `array_get($exception->guards(), 0)` method has been deprecated.

Hence to get this working, copy and paste the following code to the bottom of your `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` file;

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }


    // Checks if the guard is 'admin', 'superuser' else it returns the default
    $guard = Arr::get($exception->guards(), 0);

    switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            $login = 'admin.login';
            break;

        case 'superuser':
            $login = 'super.login';
            break;

        default:
            $login = 'login';
            break;
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route($login));
}
```

And also, don't forget to include the namespace along with these specific imports at the top of the Handler.php file, for this to work.

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;
```